# How to create Lubuntu AMI image on Amazon?

Tags: amazon-ec2, lubuntu, amazon

WOndering to create a Lubuntu (not Ubuntu) AMI image on amazon ?
Most of the AMI areon Ubuntu, so am not how to get installed Lubuntu from scratch ?

http://lubuntu.net/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved it, for people interested in it.

1) When Creating EC2 instance Free Tier Ubuntu 16.0 version of AMI
2) After the Install, go to the Instance webstei with Firefox, so you can launch SSH from the Browser.

3) When being in the terminal, type the follow
sudo apt-get install lxde-core     #For only Core version of LXDE 500Mo

or  sudo apt-get install lxde    #for Full version

4) Install also VNC Server with apt-get

5) Stop the Instance and create an AMI Image from the instance.
Be careful, you will be charged on the AMI maintenance.